# Differentiate between Screen On or Screen Off by Power button and Proximity Sensor

Tags: android

I am building an app which uses Power Button counts to perform some action, I have a BroadcastReceiver and a Service that helps me doing that. I am using ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_USER_PRESENT as intent filters, everything works fine and the power button on every press performs the action I want it to, but the Proximity Sensor does work with the same scenario I guess with the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON. So when a user makes a call and my service is running in the background checks for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON so the same action is performed by Proximity Sensor when the caller takes the  device away and towards his/her ear. I want to differentiate here the Power Button press and the Proximity sensor actions. What should I follow in order to get this done? Here is some part of my code which might help you understand what I am trying to ask.

My class extending Service has the following code in its onCreate():

```
mReceiver=new PowerButtonActionReciever();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

The Class extending BroadcastReceiver catches the Power Button Click in its onReceive() method:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
         //perform some action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a listener for proximity sensor and perform the same check as phone application.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private Sensor mProximity;

  @Override
  public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get an instance of the sensor service, and use that to get an instance of
    // a particular sensor.
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
  }

  @Override
  public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
  }

  @Override
  public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float distance = event.values[0];
    // Do something with this sensor data.
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    // Register a listener for the sensor.
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    // Be sure to unregister the sensor when the activity pauses.
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }
}
```